# iText 8.0.1 not giving correct current cursor position

Tags: java, itext7

I am using `iText 8.0.1` and following this knowledgebase item to get the current cursor position [How to find out the current cursor position on a page?](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-find-out-the-current-cursor-position-on-a-page)

But, it is not working as I expect. I am getting the same values even after adding additional content.

Here is a sample class:

```
package com.propfinancing.iTextTest;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AbstractElement;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.layout.LayoutArea;
import com.itextpdf.layout.layout.LayoutContext;
import com.itextpdf.layout.layout.LayoutResult;
import com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.IRenderer;
import java.io.File;

public class ITextTest {

  public void run() 
  throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\Tmp\\test.pdf");
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);    
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);    
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.LETTER);
    doc.setMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Paragraph 1");
    doc.add(paragraph);
    showCurrentPosition(paragraph,doc);

    paragraph = new Paragraph("Paragraph 2");
    doc.add(paragraph);
    showCurrentPosition(paragraph,doc);

    doc.close();
  }
  
  private void showCurrentPosition(AbstractElement<?> element, Document doc) {
    IRenderer renderer = element.createRendererSubTree().setParent(doc.getRenderer());
    LayoutResult layoutResult = renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, new Rectangle(595-72, 842-72))));
    Rectangle bbox = layoutResult.getOccupiedArea().getBBox();
    float x = bbox.getX();
    float y = bbox.getY();
    float width = bbox.getWidth();
    float height = bbox.getWidth();
    System.out.println("Current position is ("+x+","+y+"), width="+width+", height="+height);    
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws Exception {
    new ITextTest().run();
  }
}
```

I am getting this output:

```
Current position is (0.0,744.018), width=523.0, height=523.0
Current position is (0.0,744.018), width=523.0, height=523.0
```

The position should have changed after adding the second paragraph.

Am I misunderstanding how this works?